# Move class/style based on input range value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how I can highlight only the paragraph that at any moment correspondes to value retrieved from the input with a type of range.

When I move the slider I want to add a class to the paragraph which correspondes to the input value at that given time. I have achieved setting the class (I just used inline styling to test with), but how can I also at the same time remove the class from all the other paragraphs which don't correspond to the value?

This is what I got now:

```
<input id="part" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="6" step="1">

<p class="update-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In nobis nemo porro saepe facere minus!</p>
<p class="update-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p class="update-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem impedit neque odio, aut. Quos sapiente quisquam molestias, fugit iste aliquid, aperiam porro cumque quaerat pariatur obcaecati.</p>
<p class="update-4">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<p class="update-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, eius dolorum consectetur.</p>
<p class="update-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, dolore nesciunt nisi porro odit explicabo debitis? Iure qui, impedit fugiat officia itaque dolores. Laudantium.</p>
```

JS / jQuery:

```
var p = document.getElementById('part');

p.addEventListener('input', function () {
    $('p.update-' + p.value).css('color', 'red');
}, false )
```

Answer (score 2):

On the following example, when the range input moves, all `<p>` elements are changed to the `.transparent` class, then the selected one receives the new `.selected` class.

```js
function highlight(){

var x = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
x[i].className = "transparent";
}
  
var sell = document.getElementById("parag").value;  
document.getElementById("a" + sell).className = "selected";
  
}
```

```css
body {
background: #f7f7f7;
}

.selected {
color: #000000;
background: rgba(215, 255, 0, 0.8);
}

.transparent {
color: #666666;
background: transparent;  
}
```

```html
<input id=parag type="range" name="range" min="1" max="6" step="1" oninput="highlight()">

<p id=a1 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In nobis nemo porro saepe facere minus!</p>
<p id=a2 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p id=a3 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem impedit neque odio, aut. Quos sapiente quisquam molestias, fugit iste aliquid, aperiam porro cumque quaerat pariatur obcaecati.</p>
<p id=a4 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<p id=a5 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, eius dolorum consectetur.</p>
<p id=a6 class="transparent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, dolore nesciunt nisi porro odit explicabo debitis? Iure qui, impedit fugiat officia itaque dolores. Laudantium.</p>
```

Comment: **add class:** `document.getElementById("id").className += "classname";` **substitute class:** `document.getElementById("id").className = "classname";` **removeclass (jQuery):** `$("element").removeClass("class");`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution only using javascript and reducing the number of operations is:

```js
// save the previous selected paragraph
var oldSelectedParagraph = null;

window.onload= function(e) {
  document.getElementById('part').addEventListener('change', function () {
    // if the previous selected paragraph exists remove the attribute
    if (oldSelectedParagraph != null) {
      oldSelectedParagraph[0].style.color = '';
    }
    //save current selected paragraph if valid and set the attribute
    oldSelectedParagraph = document.querySelectorAll('p.update-' + this.value);
    if (oldSelectedParagraph.length == 1) {
      oldSelectedParagraph[0].style.color = 'red';
    } else {
      oldSelectedParagraph = null;
    }
  }, false )
}
```

```html
<input id="part" type="range" min="1" max="6" value="6" step="1">

<p class="update-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In nobis nemo porro saepe facere minus!</p>
<p class="update-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p class="update-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem impedit neque odio, aut. Quos sapiente quisquam molestias, fugit iste aliquid, aperiam porro cumque quaerat pariatur obcaecati.</p>
<p class="update-4">Lorem ipsum dolor.</p>
<p class="update-5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat, eius dolorum consectetur.</p>
<p class="update-6">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, dolore nesciunt nisi porro odit explicabo debitis? Iure qui, imped</p>
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for :)